# How to convert Local Date Time to UTC and UTC to specific TimeZone using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

1) `var sd = new Date("2018-02-20T00:00:00");`

I want to convert this local date to UTC DateTime.

2) How to convert **"2018-02-20T08:00:00Z"** this UTC date to **"India Standard Time"** or any timezone standard.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: is there any alternative way except moment.js?

Answer (score 0):

```
var isoDate = new Date('2018-02-22').toISOString();
```

Answer (score -1):

This might Work:

```
var sd = new Date("2018-02-20T00:00:00");

var utc = new Date(sd.getUTCFullYear(), sd.getUTCMonth(), sd.getUTCDate(),  sd.getUTCHours(), sd.getUTCMinutes(), sd.getUTCSeconds());
```